# Squid behind Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, http, ssl, squid

I need to locate a **Squid** instance as a forward proxy **behind Apache 2.4.6**. [I don't have enough credits to add inline images. But here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORf4n.png)

As Squid3.3 listens on localhost:3128 and works OK with default config, I have this configuration vhost config for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
    SSLEngine on
       [cert file config]
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyRemote * http://127.0.0.1:3128
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/tunnel_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/tunnel_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However my proxy requests are not processed through Squid 3.3 anyhow.

I have ran into a lot of articles around the web explaining caching in front of Apache, however, *(maybe I missed)* I need Apache to be welcoming CONNECT requests and passing to Squid.

Do you have any idea how to do the configuration?

## .

## .

## Edit

Trying with **proxypass**

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3128/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3128/
```

Apache seems to redirect my request to Squid semi-well. Because Squid this time warns me with:

```
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: /
    "Invalid URL"
Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect.
Some possible problems are:
    * Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be http:// or similar)
    * Missing hostname
    * Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path
    * Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.
Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

Because it seems like Squid thinks I would like to get http://icanhazip.com as a page from my own server. (Or am I mistaken?)

```
==> apache access log <==
1.1.1.1.myip - - [03/Apr/2014:23:33:26 +0300] "GET http://icanhazip.com/ HTTP/1.1" 400 2006 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
==> squid3 access.log <==
1396557520.935      0 127.0.0.1 NONE/400 2006 GET / - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

.
.

## Edit 2 - The Diagram

Disred solution would be like:

1) Since I couldnot still find a way out. I would like to improve the question as suggested with a diagram.

2) I have noticed while examining the headers that

```
GET /
Host: yahoo com
```

which is passed from Apache to Squid should be

```
GET http:\\yahoo.com
```

for instance to be able to work this out.

Diagram URL is at top.

Comment: I'm not completely sure as to what you're trying to achieve, but you're not actually making Apache proxy anything. You need something like `ProxyPass`.

Comment: I have put that details in the edit.

Comment: Well that can't work either, naturally. A forward proxy is not a web server. Instead, please describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can comply with this not being a standard scenario such that APACHE is in front of SQUID. SQUID is not a web server, but though is a forward proxy with limited support to SSL handling. You cannot enable SQUID with multiple SSL domains with one instance. And there are other things too. So this is what I try to do. APACHE to transparently pass my requests to/from SQUID.

Comment: Are you sure you even want a forward proxy? You still haven't described your project in its entirety. It's very important to do so. With diagrams please. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: There will be a web site served through SSL (443) port as usual any web site. However there at the same time we would like to accept also forward proxy requests and pass them over to SQUID instead of processing with mod_http_proxy which we do right now. Becuase the user authentication is handled by Apache and we won't do any with SQUID.

Answer (score 0):

combination of
   `ProxyRemote * http://localhost:3128`
with 
   `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$    http://$1   [P,L]` solved a similar problem for me.

Comment: I will give it a try soon

Comment: I have tried but didnot work either. I suppose it's better to use [the way this guy does](http://support4tech.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/youtube-caching-with-squid-nginx/) and connection would be this way: incoming > squid > nginx (as youtube downloader ie.) > apache (as dynamic web handler ie.) > response.

Comment: I needed a reverse proxy before squid. The problem is that squid for some reason couldn't handle request like that: http://installer:9999/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Contents-amd64.gz, with the help of mod_rewrite and mod_proxy It could rewrite requests ( basically strip slash in the beginning ) and then squid accepts them. here is the short article: http://male.donotuse.de/gblog/posts/squid-deb-proxy-frontend/ , your problem seem to be more complicated.

Comment: I have found the problem. It's all about the "GET" command in header. It should be with hostname but it's not. It's just "GET /" instead of "GET http://blabla.com/". (ssl is not on yet)